# Cluster Analysis Sample Size for Diss Proposal

Tags: clustering, sample-size

My psychology dissertation will be a cluster analysis with one grouping variable.  How do I know how many participants I need?  I imagine there should not be more than 5 clusters.  79 items make up 9 attributes that the participants will be clustered on.  I realize that power analysis is moot since cluster analysis is not inferential.  I have seen that for factor analysis it is 10 per item but cannot seem to find a guideline for cluster analysis.

Thanks for any help or insight you can offer.

Answer (score 1):

You never know, before you have the data.

In particular with small sample sizes, it's easy to tweak parameters, preprocessing, algorithms etc. to get out *whichever answer you like*.

Do not assume that the output of a cluster analysis is "correct". There is no such thing as correct. Either the results lead to insights (which you should then verify in a second experiment) or not. Consider cluster analysis a tool to find out which questions to ask; but not as a means to prove that you have found anything.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't fly for my proposal.  Can I use G-Power and simply calculate for MANOVA?  Or use factor analysis recs of 10 per item?  And what would be the precedent for that? I am having NO LUCK finding anyone with recommendations.

Comment: You've got a recommendation: Don't do it!